# how to auto translate in ngx-translate using google translate API

Tags: angular, google-translate, ngx-translate

how to auto-translate a string and fill up into JSON file using ngx-translate

When I compile ngx-translate it will only set key name into JSON file but it not set the value of translation so I need to set translation of each string and label